# Structuring Vuex modules with relations

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Im relatively new to vue and vuex. I need some help with how to structure my vuex store and/or local state in the components.

I have the following data structure (facebook marketing fyi)

```
- campaigns
- adsets: Is a group of ads. Relation = campaign_id
- ads: Relation = adset_id
```

I have two pages/routes, `CampaignList.vue` (/campaign) and `CampaignShow.vue` (/campaign/{campaignId}). Each route has its own api-call to fetch campaigns in either "list"-format (/api/campaign) or a single campaign with "show"-format (/api/campaign/{id}) "Show"-format has more data.

The list as expected will list all campaigns. The show page will show the campaign data (`CampaignData` component), list all adsets (`Adsets` component) and when selecting an adset, fetch and display all ads in that adset (`Ads` component). When editing ads, a Modal component will popup. That said i need to share data between components.

How am i structuring this with vuex modules and/or local state in a component?

Do my `Show` page has it's own module, eg `campaign.js` and my `List` page `campaigns.js`? If that is the case, how to i structure the module on `Show` page?

Big question i know, but i'm really stuck here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you have in your application you can store all data in store/index.js file which is just the VUEX index file.

```
export default {
  state: {
    campaigns: [],
    adsets: [],
    ads: []
  }
}
```

When you retrieve required data (via state or if modifications needed - getters) to 
`CampaignShow.vue` you can and probably should pass data to components via `props`
The same applies to the Modal component.

Comment: It will not be all, its only the "Campaign"-section. How do i handle a "showById" in the store? Do i fetch one item from backend and add it to the `campaigns` array, then select it by finding it in the array? The array will only contain one item then.. ?

Comment: It depends very much on what you trying to achieve. But either way, you can push 1 campaign or you can load all campaigns altogether. Simply use `mutators` in the store. More about it [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

To get `campaigns` by inside store use getters: 
```
getters: {
   campaignById: (state) => campaignId => {
     state.campaigns.find(({id}) => id === campaignId)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about the getters and stuff. What answer i'm seeking is if the campaigns array also should handle the "show"-page even though it only contains one item?. I will not fetch all campaigns on that page because they will not be used.

Comment: Since you probably fetch all the campaigns on the `CampaignList` page, you might as well just work with the data. There are multiple fast solutions finding data in complex structures (like array of objects).

Comment: @ZedHome I edited my post. The two pages are routes, maybe not that clear. So i can go to CampaignShow without passing CampaignList. Then the campaigns won't be loaded. I think it is unnecessary to fetch all campaigns when i only need one.. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension of what Mantas Daračiūnas has already answered. 
As showing in picture use @click=function(id) in CampaignList.vue then use state/getters values in function to look for this campaign.
(I am assuming there is only one API to get all the data)

Then you can dispatch this data in store to be accessed in CampaignShow.vue or pass them as props directly in CampaignShow.vue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain! The two pages List and Show are two routes. I have one call for each route: /campaign for fetching all campaigns in "list"-format and "/campaign/{id}" for the show-format (more data here). Then i fetch ads and adsets by eg "/campaign/{id}/ads and so on. If i want to run with modules, show adsets and ads be there own module?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about vuex modules. They are just for keeping data arranged in different files for understanding. As such they will have not effect on logic. Regarding the routes, you can push them after triggering action  this.$store.dispatch('action').then((res) => { this.$router.push({    }); }).

Comment: If you have more than one api, that will make it more easier as you can trigger the ads api from @click=function(id) then store that in ads state. Better way is to use @click=function(id) pass this id and  trigger that ads api from store action then store the result in ads state(if reqd) and access it in new route. like  this.$store.dispatch('action').then((res) => { this.$router.push({    }); })